# Metro design on my projects

Tags: microsoft-metro

Can i style my websites with metro design from windows 8/windows phone 7 for free?
Does microsoft charge anything for that?
Just answer, whether i can or not. If no - describe why.

Comment: I doubt Microsoft can patent text in boxes. It's just too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metro is two things. It is an execution shell inside Windows 8. But, it is also a design language - prescriptive guidance for developers on how to layout, style, and create excellent user experiences. The first is part of Windows 8. The second is just a guide or a style which designers and developers can use to help them choose their UI and UX.

If your web site conforms to the principles of the Metro design language, and as a result looks "Metro", then good for you. Microsoft does not own a "look". The design language is intended to improve software and to help developers. **You're good, buddy. Carry on.**